# Why was porygon in this episode of Pokémon

Tags: pokemon

I watched this

and he said "porygon" I thought porygon was banned so pokemon couldn't use it becouse of the seizure incident. Yes, I know porygon are in some of the games but those are the games and not the anime.

Why did the guy say "porygon" at 12m40s in the episode!? Is'nt it banned from the anime forever but not the games

Answer (score 2):

Porygon, the episode featuring Porygon the Pokémon from the original series, was "banned" due to having some sequences with rapidly flashing white and blue lights. These sequences can cause epileptic seizures in a small population of people.

The Pokémon itself was not banned, and it appeared some times in both the original and sequel series. In this case, the principal is making some lame pun that is lost in translation to english, which aside from hurting your sense of hunor, will not induce seizures. There is no ban on the Pokémon or just it's name.